# Weird Compiling/Linking Issue While Adding Objects in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, object, compiler-errors

I'm running into a weird compilation issue, and I don't even know if it is a compiling or linking or syntax problem or what.  Sorry to be so vague, but I'm struggling to even diagnose this problem.

To explain:  I am in the middle of writing a fairly large Java program - for me, anyway.  In my code, I set up an array of "widget" objects.  The widgets are defined a "widget.java," file; the code which creates and populates the widget array is in another file.  Trying to figure this out before I posted anything, I stripped down my code and wrote a little toy version, below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.NullPointerException;

public class arrayObjTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    widget yellow = new widget("Yellow");

    widget[] myWidgets = new widget[3];

    myWidgets[0] = new widget("Blue");  
    myWidgets[1] = new widget("Red");   
    myWidgets[2] = yellow;  

    }
}

class widget {

    String color;

    public widget(String a) {
      color = a;
    }
}
```

The toy version (above) compiles just fine.  But when I import just this...

```
129      widget[] myWidgets = new widget[3];
130      
131      myWidgets[0] = new widget("Blue");
```

...into my big code, I get these compilation errors:

```
C:\Users\Pete\Desktop\Java Playground\widgetSim>
C:\Users\Pete\Desktop\Java Playground\widgetSim>
C:\Users\Pete\Desktop\Java Playground\widgetSim>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\javac.exe" widgetMachine.java
.\widgetObject.java:131: error: ']' expected
        myWidgets[0] = new widget("Blue");
                  ^
.\widgetObject.java:131: error: ';' expected
        myWidgets[0] = new widget("Blue");
                   ^
.\widgetObject.java:131: error: illegal start of type
        myWidgets[0] = new widget("Blue");
                     ^
.\widgetObject.java:131: error: <identifier> expected
        myWidgets[0] = new widget("Blue");
                      ^
.\widgetObject.java:131: error: ';' expected
        myWidgets[0] = new widget("Blue");
                          ^
.\widgetObject.java:131: error: illegal start of type
        myWidgets[0] = new widget("Blue");
                                 ^
.\widgetObject.java:131: error: <identifier> expected
        myWidgets[0] = new widget("Blue");
                                  ^
.\widgetObject.java:131: error: ';' expected
        myWidgets[0] = new widget("Blue");
                                        ^
.\widgetObject.java:131: error: cannot find symbol
        myWidgets[0] = new widget("Blue");
        ^
  symbol:   class myWidgets
  location: class widgetObject

9 errors

C:\Users\Pete\Desktop\Java Playground\widgetSim>
C:\Users\Pete\Desktop\Java Playground\widgetSim>
C:\Users\Pete\Desktop\Java Playground\widgetSim>
```

What gives?  The compiler doesn't complain when I create an array of widgets in line 129, but when I try to insert a widget, I get the above errors.  I've tried a lot of experimenting, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I don't think its a syntax error because this code works in the toy version.  Is this some kind of linking problem?  The code creating/populating the widget array can't see "widget.java" or something?

Comment: Looks like you're writing code outside of a method, which is invalid in Java.

Comment: Umm, so just to clarify, the program above is the one that WORKS, and you're asking about a DIFFERENT program that doesn't work?  Find a needle in a haystack other than this one here?

Comment: Luiggi is entirely correct; I was writing outside a method and totally didn't catch it.  Rookie mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, you can declare an instance field within a class, and you can also initialize it. So when you write

```
 widget[] myWidgets = new widget[3];

 myWidgets[0] = new widget("Blue");
```

in the middle of a class, but outside of any method, the first line is allowable because it defines an instance field `myWidgets` and initializes it.

But the second line isn't of this type. It's just some executable code. That isn't allowed outside of a method.

Specifically, the compiler is complaining about the `0` because it **would possibly** have been valid if that line had started with

```
myWidgets[]
```

and `myWidgets` had been a class. In other words, it's not till the compiler reaches the `0` that it realises that this cannot possibly be either an instance field or the start of a method signature (it hasn't checked whether `myWidgets` is a type by that point), so that's where it complains.